# Vagrant root filesystem becomes read-only after first boot

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox

I am developing a NodeJS project and using a Vagrant VM to ensure a consistent dev environment. This **works fine for the very first boot** of the VM, but on any subsequent `vagrant up` it errors complaining about a read-only file system. Sure enough, if I run `mount` from within the VM, it shows that the root filesystem is mounted as read-only:

```
/dev/sda1 on / type ext4 (ro,relatime)
```

I can solve this by running `vagrant destroy && vagrant up`, but obviously having to entirely recreate the VM every time I use it makes using vagrant extremely slow and cumbersome.

I had a feeling it might have something to do with [this known bug regarding symlinks in VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/10085), but the solution described there does not work for me. In any case, according to the [Vagrant docs](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/synced-folders/virtualbox#sharedfoldersenablesymlinkscreate) this option is now enabled by default., so maybe that really isn't it after all.

**This is extremely annoying and driving me nuts, I hope somebody is able to help.**

Output from `vagrant up`:

```
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Checking if box 'ubuntu/impish64' version '20220204.0.0' is up to date...
==> default: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 9229 (guest) => 9229 (host) (adapter 1)
    default: 10000 (guest) => 10000 (host) (adapter 1)
    default: 22 (guest) => 2222 (host) (adapter 1)
==> default: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
==> default: Booting VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
    default: SSH username: vagrant
    default: SSH auth method: private key
==> default: Machine booted and ready!
[default] GuestAdditions 6.1.26 running --- OK.
==> default: Checking for guest additions in VM...
==> default: Mounting shared folders...
    default: /vagrant => /home/myproject
    default: /opt/A Folder => /home/myproject/folder
    default: /home/vagrant/.config/myproject => /home/myproject/config
    default: /home/vagrant/.local/share/myproject => /home/myproject/data
The following SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status.
Vagrant assumes that this means the command failed!

sed -i '/#VAGRANT-BEGIN/,/#VAGRANT-END/d' /etc/fstab

Stdout from the command:



Stderr from the command:

sed: couldn't open temporary file /etc/sedGih0MF: Read-only file system
```

Vagrantfile:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/impish64"

  # Need this plugin to forward file system events from the host to the guest
  # Otherwise watching for file changes is not going to work
  # See https://github.com/adrienkohlbecker/vagrant-fsnotify
  config.vagrant.plugins = ["vagrant-fsnotify"]

  # Expose port 9229 to allow debugging
  config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 9229, host: 9229
  # Expose port 10000 as the default port for quartersbrief
  config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 10000, host: 10000

  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
    # Give the vm more memory than the standard 1024 because we will be handling
    # large amounts of data
    vb.memory = "2048"
    vb.name = "myproject"
  end

  # Install NodeJS
  config.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<-SHELL
    curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_17.x | sudo -E bash -
    sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
    sudo npm install -g grunt-cli
  SHELL

  # Set NODE_ENV to 'development' by default
  config.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<-SHELL
    echo "export NODE_ENV=development" > /etc/profile.d/node-env.sh
  SHELL

  # Share data directory as per XDG Base Directory Specification
  # https://specifications.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/latest/index.html
  config.vm.synced_folder "data/", "/home/vagrant/.local/share/myproject
  # Share config directory as per XDG Base Directory Specification
  # https://specifications.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/latest/index.html
  config.vm.synced_folder "config/", "/home/vagrant/.config/myproject
  config.vm.synced_folder "folder/", "/opt/A Folder", fsnotify: true

  # cd to the /vagrant directory upon login
  config.ssh.extra_args = ["-t", "cd /vagrant; bash --login"]

  config.trigger.after :up do |t|
    t.name = "vagrant fsnotify"
    t.run = { inline: "vagrant fsnotify" }
  end
end
```

**Update:**
I have eliminated [fsnotify](https://github.com/adrienkohlbecker/vagrant-fsnotify) as the cause of the problem. Even after destroying the VM, deleting `.vagrant` folder and commenting out everything to do with `fsnotify` in the `Vagrantfile`, the problem remains: After one boot that goes fine, all subsequent `vagrant up`s error out with `read-only file system`.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a bug in Vagrant that occurs when a synced folder's name on the guest machine contains spaces.

I have filed a [bug report](https://github.com/hashicorp/vagrant/issues/12697).